# How to check if a variable has been constructed with a constructor?

Tags: constructor, elm

Given

```elm
type Bla = A Int | B Int

valA1 = A 1
valA2 = A 2
```

is there a way for me to check whether `valA1` has been constructed with the constructor of `valA2`?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 6):

There is no general purpose way of comparing constructors but you could put together your own function easily:

```elm
isSameBlaConstructor : Bla -> Bla -> Bool
isSameBlaConstructor x y =
    case (x, y) of
        (A _, A _) -> True
        (B _, B _) -> True
        _ -> False
```